# Best practice for dealing with bidi's redefinitions for class authors

Tags: documentclass-writing, bidi

As is well-documented elsewhere, `bidi.sty` does a lot of redeclarations and assumes that the author is using one of a small set of document classes. For use of packages, one can fiddle with the order of `\usepackage` in the preamble, but what's the best practice for class authors to get around bidi's redefinitions of various document structures?

Comment: bidi patches code not written with rtl scripts in mind, so best recommendation for writing a new class would be to make sure it works in conjunction with the standard babel bidi support and tell users they don't need to load bidi as bidirectional text is supported.

Comment: bidi gets loaded implicitly by Polyglossia if you specify `\otherlanguage{hebrew}` I got around this issue in my book by replacing the examples of Hebrew with Greek, but when I get to the document class writing book. I should address this. The existing solution is rather invasive if one wants to simply write ברשית in one's document. Babel's default settings for Hebrew are effectively broken as the default wants to load a font that isn't installed in a normal installation. babel kind of belongs in the legacy bin of LaTeX based on my experiments with it.

Comment: babel's hebrew in lualatex works fine, you can find a number of examples here, only the ldf file for pdflatex is broken, but you couldn't use that with polyglossia/bidi either.

Comment: @DonHosek not really: babel is the actively maintained standard latex language interface, if you find an issue with it please raise an issue at https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues